# Criar método que evite repetição de código em ASP.NET com SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

Estou construindo um site em ASP.NET, utilizando C#. Quero 'linkar' as informações do site (textos e imagens) num banco de dados SQL Server. Essa parte de conexão eu já consegui fazer com sucesso.

Porém, tenho que **repetir** a codificação da conexão do BD para cada grupo de labels e imagens do meu site, e isso está gerando uma repetição de códigos desnecessária. 
Gostaria de ajuda para criar um método que resolvesse meu problema, e que não me fizesse repetir códigos desnecessariamente.

Código HTML da minha página aspx:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- MÓDULO 1-->

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            <h2><asp:Label ID="lbl_modulo1" runat="server"></asp:Label></h2>
            <p><asp:Label ID="lbl_texto_modulo1" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba Mais</a>
            <!--FIM do MÓDULO 1-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- MÓDULO 2-->
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
            <h2><asp:Label ID="lbl_modulo2" runat="server"></asp:Label></h2>
            <p><asp:Label ID="lbl_texto_modulo2" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba Mais</a>
            <!--FIM do MÓDULO 2-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <!-- MÓDULO 3-->
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" />
            <h2><asp:Label ID="lbl_modulo3" runat="server"></asp:Label></h2>
            <p><asp:Label ID="lbl_texto_modulo3" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba Mais</a>
            <!--FIM do MÓDULO 3-->
        </div>

    </div>
```

E aqui está o código em C#, utilizado na conexão com banco:

```
 public partial class Teste_Footer : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    //CONEXÃO COM BANCO        
    string connStr = @"DATA SOURCE = .\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = website; USER Id = sa; Password = 123456;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

    conn.Open();

    //CRIAÇÃO DO COMANDO
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IMAGEM_CAMINHO, TITULO, TEXTO FROM [dbo].[PAG_SITE] WHERE ID='1'");
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    string imagem = "";
    string titulo = "";
    string texto = "";

    //LENDO DO BANCO
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        imagem += reader["IMAGEM_CAMINHO"].ToString();
        titulo += reader["TITULO"].ToString();
        texto += reader["TEXTO"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();

    Image1.ImageUrl += imagem;
    lbl_modulo1.Text = titulo;
    lbl_texto_modulo1.Text = texto;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    conn.Open();

    //CRIAÇÃO DO COMANDO
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT IMAGEM_CAMINHO, TITULO, TEXTO FROM [dbo].[PAG_SITE] WHERE ID='2'");
    cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd2.Connection = conn;

    string imagem2 = "";
    string titulo2 = "";
    string texto2 = "";

    //LENDO DO BANCO
    SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader2.Read())
    {
        imagem2 += reader2["IMAGEM_CAMINHO"].ToString();
        titulo2 += reader2["TITULO"].ToString();
        texto2 += reader2["TEXTO"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();

    Image2.ImageUrl += imagem2;
    lbl_modulo2.Text = titulo2;
    lbl_texto_modulo2.Text = texto2;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    conn.Open();

    //CRIAÇÃO DO COMANDO
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT IMAGEM_CAMINHO, TITULO, TEXTO FROM [dbo].[PAG_SITE] WHERE ID='3'");
    cmd3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd3.Connection = conn;

    string imagem3 = "";
    string titulo3 = "";
    string texto3 = "";

    //LENDO DO BANCO
    SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader3.Read())
    {
        imagem3 += reader3["IMAGEM_CAMINHO"].ToString();
        titulo3 += reader3["TITULO"].ToString();
        texto3 += reader3["TEXTO"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();

    Image3.ImageUrl += imagem3;
    lbl_modulo3.Text = titulo3;
    lbl_texto_modulo3.Text = texto3;              

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //CONEXÃO COM BANCO        
        string connStr = @"DATA SOURCE = .\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = website; USER Id = sa; Password = 123456;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT IMAGEM_CAMINHO, TITULO, TEXTO FROM [dbo].[PAG_SITE] WHERE ID IN ('1', '2', '3')", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(tb);

        for(int i =0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var img = this.FindControl("Image" + (i+1)) as Image;
            var lbl = this.FindControl("lbl_modulo" + (i+1)) as Label;
            var lbltexto = this.FindControl("lbl_texto_modulo" + (i+1)) as Label;

            img.ImageUrl = tb.Rows[i]["IMAGEM_CAMINHO"] as string;
            lbl.Text = tb.Rows[i]["TITULO"] as string;
            lbltexto.Text = tb.Rows[i]["TEXTO"] as string;
        }
```

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado.

Comment: Sempre as ordens    :)

Answer (score 1):

Como boas práticas de programação seria mais interessante você criar um sistema em três camadas. Onde cada camada cumpre com sua responsabilidade.

> Camada de apresentação

HTML e chamadas a camada de negócio no CodeBehind

```
public partial class Teste_Footer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            RegrasNegocio obj = new RegrasNegocio();
            Tipo Retorno = new Tipo();

            //Chama a camada de negócio
            Retorno = obj.Consultar(1);

            // Utiliza o objeto de retorno
            Image1.ImageUrl += Retorno.IMAGEM_CAMINHO;
            lbl_modulo1.Text = Retorno.TITULO;
            lbl_texto_modulo1.Text = Retorno.TEXTO;

 //Chama a camada de negócio
            Retorno = obj.Consultar(2);

            // Utiliza o objeto de retorno
            Image2.ImageUrl += Retorno.IMAGEM_CAMINHO;
            lbl_modulo2.Text = Retorno.TITULO;
            lbl_texto_modulo2.Text = Retorno.TEXTO;

 //Chama a camada de negócio
            Retorno = obj.Consultar(3);

            // Utiliza o objeto de retorno
            Image3.ImageUrl += Retorno.IMAGEM_CAMINHO;
            lbl_modulo3.Text = Retorno.TITULO;
            lbl_texto_modulo3.Text = Retorno.TEXTO;

        }
    }
```

> Camada de negócio

Onde você atribui todas a regras de negócio do seu sistema como por exemplo validações.

```
 public class RegrasNegocio
    {

        public Tipo Consultar(Int32 ID)
        {

            AcessoDados obj = new AcessoDados();
            Tipo Retorno = new Tipo();

            try
            {

                // Regras de negócio

                if (ID == 0)
                    throw new Exception("ID não informado.");

                //Chama a camada responsável pelo acesso aos dados e conexão com o banco
                Retorno = obj.ConsultarPorID(ID);

                return Retorno;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }


    }
```

> Camada de acesso a dados

Conexao com o banco de dados e chamadas a ele.

```
class AcessoDados
    {

        public Tipo ConsultarPorID(Int32 ID)
        {

            // Criação do objeto tipo para retorno do método
            Tipo Objetoretorno = new Tipo();


            //CONEXÃO COM BANCO        
            // Adicionar Referência System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Retorna a string do web Config
            string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["root"].ConnectionString;  
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            conn.Open();

            //CRIAÇÃO DO COMANDO
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IMAGEM_CAMINHO, TITULO, TEXTO FROM [dbo].[PAG_SITE] WHERE ID=@ID"); // Utilize Procedures SLQ 

            // Utilize paramentros para o método ser dinâmico
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID; 

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            //LENDO DO BANCO
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Objetoretorno.IMAGEM_CAMINHO = reader["IMAGEM_CAMINHO"].ToString();
                Objetoretorno.TITULO = reader["TITULO"].ToString();
                Objetoretorno.TEXTO = reader["TEXTO"].ToString();
            }

            conn.Close();

            //Retorna um objeto que vai ser utilizado no codeBehind
            return Objetoretorno;

        }

    }
```

> Camada de Apoio Objeto tipo que representa uma entidade

```
 public class Tipo
    {
        public String IMAGEM_CAMINHO { get; set; }
        public String TITULO { get; set; }
        public String TEXTO { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A conexao pode ser uma classe c# (Models/DataAcess.cs). Arquivo DataAcess.cs

```
public class DataAcess{
   public DataAcess(){
      //Colque sua String de Conexão  aqui
      //Retorne a variavel de conexao.
   }
```

Dai na seu Código de Page_Load vc irá fazer o seguinte

```
//Chama seu Model DataAcess
var conexao = DataAcess();
conexao.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria você utilizar o ConfigurationManager, ou seja armazenar a string de conexão no web.config do seu site:

1. Colocar a string de conexão no seu WebConfig:

   ```
     <connectionStrings>
           <add name="root" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=seubanco;User ID=root;Password=suasenha;"/>
       </connectionStrings>
   ```
2. No Code Behind ou Classe que for utilizar a conexão você inclui o namespace System.Configuration:

   ```
   using System.Configuration;
   ```
3. Depois só atribuir a uma string chamando a conexão do web.config

   string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["root"].ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

Comment: Olá Willian, obrigado pela atenção, porém meu problema não é com a string de conexão com o banco, mesmo sua dica sendo plausível. Meu objetivo é evitar a repetição de códigos na parte em que eu uso o SELECT para buscar as informações no banco.

Comment: Adicionei outra resposta verifique se te atende.